# Azure DevOps CI/CD Msbuild task minify.targets not working

Tags: continuous-integration, devops, continuous-deployment, msbuild-task

While creating DevOps CI/CD using TFS online using MSBuild.

I have two projects under the single solution one is web project and another one is web static project which taking care CSS/JS/images.

#1 Web DevOps msbuild and Release working fine without any issue, but #2 web static project not creating `minify.targets` into `xx.min.cs` or `xx.min.js`. Same working fine in local environment.

```
<PostBuildEvent>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe $(ProjectDir)\static\myproject\msbuild\minify\minify.targets /p:ProjectDir=$(ProjectDir)</PostBuildEvent>
```

Comment: Please include your build configuration, otherwise nobody can really tell why the minified files are not created. Did you inspect your logs? Maybe enhance the verbosity and check what steps are performed on the server which could lead you to the reason the files are missing

Comment: @Capricorn Added the build configuration

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding the Propertygroup as shown below

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == 'false' Or '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' != 'true'">
    <PostBuildEvent>$(MSBuildBinPath)\msbuild.exe $(ProjectDir)\static\myproject\msbuild\minify\minify.targets /p:ProjectDir=$(ProjectDir)</PostBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
```